# Extending Twig: parse html tags

Tags: php, coffeescript, twig

Is it possible to extend Twig to parse <tag>...</tag> string?

I know what i can extend twig to parse {% tag %} {% endtag %}.

But how to parse html tags?

I want to parse

```
<script type="text/coffeescript">...</script>
```

to javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
```

*UPDATE*:

**Here is solution**: https://github.com/Elfet/CoffeeBundle

Comment: Are you using Symfony? If you want to parse coffee script there are current ways to do this already. For example: http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/05/16/symfony2-using-coffeescript-with-assetic/

Comment: Yes, i use Symfony and i know this. I want to write inline coffee scripts in html.

Comment: You can create your own token parsers in Twig. Here's one tutorial: http://mark-story.com/posts/view/making-custom-tags-in-twig You can also look at some of the built in parsers as examples: https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions/tree/master/lib/Twig/Extensions/TokenParser

Comment: In this tutorial they parse {% script 'js/jquery.js' %} string. With "{%", "%}". I need to parse "<", ">" html tags!

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to make Twig parse <..> tags. Everything twig supports has to be inside {{..}} or {%..%} delimiters.